# Need help computing rolling sums in R for groups

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with 4 columns: ID, Cat, Date, and Val.   I would like to create 2 new columns in this table which have the 3month and 12month rolling sums of Val, grouped by ID and Cat.  Ideally I'd like a data.table solution, since I have a very large data set. Additionally, I may have missing data in certain months for a specific group of ID/Cat, so that month should be skipped in the calculation.

This will create a sample data table to work with.

```
sample_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow =34, ncol = 4))

colnames(sample_data) <- c("ID", "Cat", "Date", "Val")

sample_data$ID <- c("PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", 
                    "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", 
                    "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG")

sample_data$Cat <- c("MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", 
                      "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", 
                      "MM", "MM", "MM", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE")

sample_data$Date <- c(
"2018-12-31", "2018-11-30", "2018-10-31", "2018-09-30", "2018-08-31",
"2018-07-31", "2018-06-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-04-30", "2018-03-31",
"2018-02-28", "2018-01-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-11-30",
"2018-10-31", "2018-09-30", "2018-08-31", "2018-07-31", "2018-06-30",
"2018-05-31", "2018-04-30", "2018-03-31", "2018-02-28", "2018-01-31",
"2017-12-31", "2017-11-30", "2017-10-31", "2017-09-30", "2017-08-31",
"2017-07-31", "2017-06-30", "2017-05-31", "2017-04-30")

sample_data$Val <- c(-11, 84, 74, 80, -9, 
                     -40, -76, -47, -50, -50, 
                     97, 42, 44, 53, 1, 
                     13, 65, 52, -5, 75, 
                     -41, -6, 8, -79, 53, 
                     22, -100, -57, -89, 28, 
                     37, -24, 17, -53)
```

I have searched various stackoverflow solutions, but am unable to get anything to work.  Most solutions deal with a group on just one column,not multiple, and only do a single rolling sum, not multiple.

Here is something I started, but wasn't able to implement correctly.

```
sample_data <- sample_data[, cumsum3mo := sample_data[.(ID, Cat, Date, (Date - day(Date)+1) %m-% months(2) - 1), 
                       on = .(ID = V1, Cat = V2, Date <= V3, Date > V4), 
                       sum(Val), by = .EACHI]][]
```

This is the expected output:

```
sample_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow =34, ncol = 6))

colnames(sample_data) <- c("ID", "Cat", "Date", "Val", "cumsum3mo", "cumsum12mo")

sample_data$ID <- c("PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", 
                    "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", 
                    "PMM", "PMM", "PMM", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", 
                    "LCG", "LCG", "LCG", "LCG")

sample_data$Cat <- c("MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", 
                      "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", 
                      "MM", "MM", "MM", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE", 
                      "OE", "OE", "OE", "OE")

sample_data$Date <- c("2018-12-31", "2018-11-30", "2018-10-31", "2018-09-30", "2018-08-31", 
                      "2018-07-31", "2018-06-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-04-30", "2018-03-31", 
                      "2018-02-28", "2018-01-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2018-11-30", 
                      "2018-10-31", "2018-09-30", "2018-08-31", "2018-07-31", "2018-06-30", 
                      "2018-05-31", "2018-04-30", "2018-03-31", "2018-02-28", "2018-01-31", 
                      "2017-12-31", "2017-11-30", "2017-10-31", "2017-09-30", "2017-08-31", 
                      "2017-07-31", "2017-06-30", "2017-05-31", "2017-04-30")

sample_data$Val <- c(-11, 84, 74, 80, -9, 
                     -40, -76, -47, -50, -50, 
                     97, 42, 44, 53, 1, 
                     13, 65, 52, -5, 75, 
                     -41, -6, 8, -79, 53, 
                     22, -100, -57, -89, 28, 
                     37, -24, 17, -53)

sample_data$cumsum3mo <- c(147, 238, 145, 31, -125, 
                     -163, -173, -147, -3, 89, 
                     183, 86, 44, 67, 79, 
                     130, 112, 122, 29, 28, 
                     -39, -77, -18, -4, -25, 
                     -135, -246, -118, -24, 41, 
                     30, -60, -36, -53)

sample_data$cumsum12mo <- c(94, 149, 65, -9, -89, 
                      -80, -40, 36, 83, 133, 
                      183, 86, 44, 189, 158, 
                      57, -13, -167, -191, -149, 
                      -248, -190, -237, -245, -166, 
                      -219, -241, -141, -84, 5, 
                      -23, -60, -36, -53)
```

Comment: I have had acceptable results using `dplyr` for data in the millions of rows using something like `mutate(cuml = cumsum(Val), cumsum3mo = Val - lag(Val, 3), cumsum12mo = Val - lag(Val, 12))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data are as of month ends, this should get you started:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample_data)
sample_data[, Date := as.Date(Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
sample_data[, c("cumsum3mo", "cumsum12mo") := .(
        sapply(Date, function(d) sum(Val[between(Date, seq(d+1L, by="-3 month", len=2L)[2L], d)])), 
        sapply(Date, function(d) sum(Val[between(Date, seq(d+1L, by="-12 months", len=2L)[2L], d)]))
    ),
    by=.(ID, Cat)]
```

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to work (I'll test for my large dataset later).  Coul you please explain the portion [between(Date, seq(d+1L, by="-3 month", len=2L)[2L], d)].  I understand Val is being summed between 2 dates (date and 3-mo ago date).  However, I'm not understanding how  the 3-mo ago date is derived in the seq statement.

Comment: 3 months ago from a month end date does not always give you a month end date. Using 1st of the month is more robust. Hence for eg using dec 31, the seq code gives oct 1.

Comment: Got it, thanks!. Was confused with the "seq" function, but looks like it just builds a stream of dates based on the Date field, with interval of -3 months or -12 months, and continues this for just 2 intervals (len=2L), and returns just the 2nd one ([2L]).  Guessing I could build this date range in other ways as well, but this works.